# eclipse project, stubs built by axis... Q2. of 3... can I use jax-ws instead to rebuild the java stubs/class files?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl, axis

Q1. So I have a webapp project in eclipse Java EE, which already has wsdl2java.xml and the stubs files in place. This was all done using an earlier version of Apache axis. Now in order to get a new wsdl2java.xml from apache axis2 would I have to re-build everything from the command line and then drop it in to my existing project? Would I be executing the wsdl2java jar in the command line designating parameters, destinations and wsdl files?

Q2. Now when I had originally tried executing the build file (wsdl2java.xml) without changing anything I received an error from java relating to "...too many parameters in java method, can not exceed over 255..." or something to that fact. Now, will axis2 or jax-ws be able to fix that problem?

and finally...

Q3. If I use jax-ws can the current stubs that I have, which were built with axis, be replaced by the new jax-ws generated stubs?

Answer (score 1):

1. If earlier version of Axis was 1.x then yes, you have to generate new stubs.
2. Axis2 provides own code-generation tool - old xml may be not very useful, prepare new one.
3. Well I do not exactly know what do you want to achieve, if you change ws runtime u have to replace stubs.